# $\frac{(p-1)!}{1}-\frac{(p-1)!}{2}+\frac{(p-1)!}{3}-\cdots-\frac{(p-1)!}{p-1} \equiv \frac{2-2^p}{p} \pmod{p}$

Tags: congruences

$p$ is an odd prime.  How to prove the following congruence?
$$\frac{(p-1)!}{1}-\frac{(p-1)!}{2}+\frac{(p-1)!}{3}-\cdots-\frac{(p-1)!}{p-1} \equiv \frac{2-2^p}{p} \pmod{p}$$ 
I have created a polynomial that the left side of this congruence is one of its coefficients but this idea not completed to solving the question.

Comment: use the Wilson theorem.

Comment: @Fermat how i use it to solve the problem?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "this idea." What idea?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews this idea that wrighting a polynomial that the summation that is in the equation is one of its coefitients and using some rules that are true in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}[x]$.

Answer (score 3):

We use the following seven binomial-coefficient identities, accompanied by brief proofs.  The main proof is farther down.

The first and second identities are $$1 = \binom p0 \qquad 1= \binom pp. \tag{1, 2}$$  Indeed, given a set with $p$ elements, there is precisely $1$ way to select $0$ elements and precisely $1$ way to select all $p$ elements.

The third identity, $$2^p = \sum_{k = 0}^p \binom pk,\tag3$$ is found by replacing $x$ and $y$ each with $1$ in the binomial theorem $$(x + y)^p = \sum_{k = 0}^p \binom pk x^ky^{p - k}.$$

The fourth and fifth identities, $$\binom pk = \binom{p - 1}{k - 1}\frac pk \qquad \binom{p - 1}k = \binom pk - \binom{p - 1}{k - 1},\tag{4, 5}$$ are verified by replacing the binomial coefficients with the their combinatorial definition.

The identities above do not actually require that $p$ be prime, but the next two do.  The sixth identity is $$\binom pk \equiv 0 \pmod p \text{ for } 1 \le k \le p - 1.\tag6$$ To prove it, use the combinatorial definition $$\binom pk = \frac{p!}{k!(p - k)!}$$  and note that because $p$ is prime and $1 \le k \le p - 1$, none of the factors in the denominator divides out the factor $p$ in the numerator.  Hence, $\binom pk$ is a multiple of $p$ and so congruent to $0$ modulo $p$.

The seventh and final identity, $$\binom{p - 1}{k - 1} \equiv (-1)^{k - 1} \pmod p \text{ for } 1 \le k \le p,\tag7$$ we prove by induction.  The claim holds for $k = 1$ because $$\binom{p - 1}{1 - 1} = \binom{p - 1}0 = 1 = (-1)^{1 - 1} \equiv (-1)^{1 - 1} \pmod p.$$  Similarly, the claim holds for $k = p$.  Suppose that the claim holds for $k = j$, $1 \le j < p$.  Then $$\binom{p - 1}{(j + 1) - 1}  = \binom{p - 1}j = \binom pj - \binom{p - 1}{j - 1} \equiv 0 + (-1)(-1)^{j - 1} = (-1)^{(j + 1) - 1} \pmod p$$  where the second equation is the fifth identity, and the congruence uses the sixth identity.  Hence, the claim holds for $k = j + 1$ whenever it holds for $k = j$, and so the induction principle guarantees that it holds for every integer $k$, $1 \le k \le p$.

We are now ready for the main proof:
\begin{align}
\frac{2 - 2^p}p & = \frac1p \left( \binom p0 + \binom pp - \sum_{k = 0}^p \binom pk \right) &&\text{first three identities}\\
& = -\frac1p \sum_{k = 1}^{p - 1} \binom pk \\
& = -\frac1p \sum_{k = 1}^{p - 1} \binom{p - 1}{k - 1} \frac pk &&\text{fourth identity}\\
& = -\sum_{k = 1}^{p - 1} \binom{p - 1}{k - 1} \frac1k \\
& \equiv -\sum_{k = 1}^{p - 1} \frac{(-1)^{k - 1}}k \pmod p &&\text{seventh identity}\\
& \equiv (p - 1)! \sum_{k = 1}^{p - 1} \frac{(-1)^{k - 1}}k \pmod p &&\text{Wilson's theorem}\\
& = \frac{(p - 1)!}1 - \frac{(p - 1)!}2 + \frac{(p - 1)!}3 - \cdots  - \frac{(p - 1)!}{p - 1}
\end{align}

Remarks:  This is Problem 14 of Section 2.7 of I. Niven, H. S. Zuckerman, H. L. Montgomery, *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers,* 5th ed., Wiley (New York), 1991.  See also [About the Fermat quotients with base $2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1951006/about-the-fermat-quotients-with-base-2).